# python nested dictionary comprehension bug?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

The following nested/double dictionary comprehension seems to give a buggy result:

```
>>> { k:v for k in range(2) for v in 'abc' }
{0: 'c', 1: 'c'}
```

The tuples for comparison:

```
>>> [ (k,v) for k in range(2) for v in 'abc' ]
[(0, 'a'), (0, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c')]
```

Same behaviour with `dict()`:

```
>>> dict( (k,v) for k in range(2) for v in 'abc' )
{0: 'c', 1: 'c'}
```

Or am I making a conceptual mistake here?

Comment: What did you expect instead? You can't have multiple values for the same key, each new value just replaces the old one.

Comment: This is because, `dict` cannot have same `key` name

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `{k : list('abc') for k in range(2)}`? But without an expected output, that's just a guess.

Comment: You are making a conceptual mistake. Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, and tuples don't have keys

Comment: oh that makes perfect sense! silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I intended to do:

```
>>> { k1: { k2 : (k1,k2) for k2 in range(2) } for k1 in range(3) }
...
{0: {0: (0, 0), 1: (0, 1)},
 1: {0: (1, 0), 1: (1, 1)},
 2: {0: (2, 0), 1: (2, 1)}}
```